# Subset based on granularity and average values

Tags: r, subset, mean

I have large `data-frame` consists of two columns. I want to calculate the average of the second column values for each subset of the first column. The subset of the first column is based on a specified granularity. For example, for the following `data-frame`, `df`, I want to calculate the average of `df$B` values for each subset of `df$A` with an increment(granularity) of 1 for each subset. The results should be in two new columns.

```
A       B            expected results     newA      newB
0.22096 1                                  0         1.142857
0.33489 1                                  1         2
0.33655 1                                  2         4
0.43953 1
0.64933 2
0.86668 1
0.96932 1
1.09342 2
1.58314 2
1.88481 2
2.07654 4
2.34652 3
2.79777 5
```

This is a simple example, I'm not sure how to loop over the whole `data-frame` and perform the calculation i.e. the average of the `df$B`.

tried below to subset, but couldn't figure how to append the results and create final results:

Tried something like :

```
increment<-1
mx<-max(df$A)
i<-0

newDF<-data.frame()
while(i < mx){
    tmp<-subset(df, (A >i & A< (i+increment)))
    i<-i+granualrity
}
```

Not sure about the logic. But I'm sure there is a short way to do the required calculation. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `findInterval` for the subset selection (In your example a simple `ceiling` for each `A` value should be sufficient, too. But if your `increment` is different from 1 you need `findInterval`.) and `tapply` to calculate the `mean`:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
A       B
0.22096 1
0.33489 1
0.33655 1
0.43953 1
0.64933 2
0.86668 1
0.96932 1
1.09342 2
1.58314 2
1.88481 2
2.07654 4
2.34652 3
2.79777 5"), header=TRUE)

## sort data.frame by column A (needed for findInterval)
df <- df[order(df$A), ]

## define granuality
subsets <- seq(1, max(ceiling(df$A)), by=1) # change the "by" argument for different increments
df$subset <- findInterval(df$A, subsets)

tapply(df$B, df$subset, mean)
#       0        1        2 
#1.142857 2.000000 4.000000
```

Comment: Does the order make any difference? think df$A already ordered !!. Yes, I want to test the data with different increment values i.e. 0.1,1 where I can specify the increment. Finally, how to have the results as 2 column dataframe !

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: If your data (df$A column) are already ordered you can skip the `order` call. I used it just for safety reasons (maybe your toy example has an ordered column but your real data have not).

Comment: Thank you. But how to change the increment value and have the results in 2 columns instead of two rows !

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: See my edited code. To turn the result into a `data.frame` you could use something like `d <- as.data.frame(tapply(...))`.

Comment: Using as.data.frame() always giving me one column i.e.(mean values) although the intervals are included e.g. this is one column dataframe.
0 1.142857
1 2.000000
2 4.000000

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: Than try `d <- as.data.frame(tapply(...)); d$subset <- rownames(d)`.